# I am install Ubuntu in Windows 7, So how to uninstall ubuntu in windows?

Tags: xubuntu, windows-7

First i am installing windows 7 then installing ubuntu. Windows 7 is my main operating system then i install ubuntu, so ubuntu install in windows Drive (c:).

Please give me a solution for how to remove only ubuntu operating system ?

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu in the first place? Did you use Wubi? Can you please post the output of `parted -l`, `gdisk -l`, or `fdisk -l`? (Please [edit] your question to add missing information.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but the best way to go about this usually is to install the second operating system as a guest VM.

You could try completely deleting the partitions that Linux sits on from inside Windows and then use the windows installation disc to fix the windows boot loader so that windows boots automatically.

I think I have had to do it that way in the past.  Hope that helps..

Comment: I am delete ubuntu operating system in c: drive in windows but how to remove the entry when my machine is boot or how to remove entry of that operating system in bootloader?

Comment: Using the windows installation disc will fix the bootloader back to just windows.  I think.. It's been a long time since I had to do it but I am pretty sure that's what I did.